# VB.net label using a session variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, textbox, label

My vb.net application needs to use a session variable. I don't really know how to use it in ASP.net. I've been trying to use what my books have, but I can't get this label to work. I need the user input to be validated against the database and if their code is in the database, the textbox should disappear and a label will appear saying Welcome.

The way I wrote it, I get an error saying the server tag is not well formed and in the codebehind it says that the ID of my label is not declared. Can anyone spot any problems with the code I wrote?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsIBs" 
Text="Welcome, <%# Eval("First_Name") %> '&' <%# Eval("Last_Name")%>">
</asp:Label>


Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal 
  args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles
  CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
    args.IsValid = True
    For Each drv As DataRowView In dsIBs.[Select](DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
        If drv("baccount").ToString() = args.Value Then
            args.IsValid = False
            lblIB.Visible = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If args.IsValid Then
        IBTextBox.Visible = False
        IBTextBoxButton.Visible = False
        lblIB.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

    Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
    args.IsValid = True
    For Each drv As DataRowView In dsIBs.[Select](DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
        If drv("baccount").ToString() = args.Value Then
            args.IsValid = False
            lblIB.Visible = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If args.IsValid Then
        IBTextBox.Visible = False
        IBTextBoxButton.Visible = False
        lblIB.Visible = True
        lblIB.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0} {1}", Session("FirstName"), Session("LastName"))

    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load
    lblIB.Visible = False
End Sub


If args.IsValid Then
   IBTextBox.Visible = False
   IBTextBoxButton.Visible = False
   lblIB.Visible = True
   lblIB.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0} {1}", Session("FirstName"),
   Session("LastName"))

    Protected Sub IBTextBoxButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles IBTextBoxButton.Click
    Session("IB") = IBTextBox.Text
    Dim IB As String = Session("IB")
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl + "&IB=" + Session("IB"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the Label inside of a databound control?

Comment: No, the label is just sitting after the textbox and button that the user uses to enter their code. There is a custom validator in there to validate a user's input against the codes in the database, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is wrong because the Label control doesn't have a DataSourceID property, so you should remove it:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" 
Text="Welcome, <%# Eval("First_Name") %> '&' <%# Eval("Last_Name")%>">
</asp:Label>
```

I would also remove the Eval expression (unless it's inside a databound control -gridview,  etc-) in the Text property and leave it as:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" 
Text="">
</asp:Label>
```

Finally, you should be able to perform your validation on the server side and set the Text programmatically doing something like:

```
lblIB.Text = "Welcome " + First_Name + " " + Last_Name
```

Where First_Name and Last_Name are read from the database somehow.

Comment: You can add the lblIB code right after the line making it visible in your code above.

Comment: I put the lblIB code after making it visible, but it says that lblIB is not declared. Do I need to set a Dim for it somewhere? I tried `As String` but it says `lbl.Text is not a member of String`

Comment: lblIB is the ID of your Label that you put in your .aspx page

<asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" />

Comment: @jlg you shouldn't need to have to do Dim since the lblIB is declared in the markup. You must be having a different kind of problem.

Comment: @Icarus I didn't think I needed to do that but it was the only thing I could think of.

Comment: I was able to use the label with session("first_name") and session("last_name"). thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you get server tag not well formed, this usually points to an issue with your quoting.

The parser gets confused over the quotes you use.

Fortunately, there is a simple solution.

Change :-

```
Text="Welcome, <%# Eval("First_Name") %> '&' <%# Eval("Last_Name")%>">
```

To:-

```
Text='Welcome, <%# Eval("First_Name") %> &#145;&amp;&#146; <%# Eval("Last_Name")%>'>
```

First, we've put single quotes around the text.  This'll help to parser to recognize where your quoted text actually ends.

Second, I assume that you actually want to display the '&', and not using it for concatenation.  That's this bit :-

```
&#145;&amp;&#146;
```

Remove if you don't need it.

Finally, if the label isn't actually being databound, then nothing will happen.  You either need to databind the label or use slightly different quoting syntax.

Quoting syntax for emitting a string in earlier versions of VS is :-

```
<%= %>
```

Quoting syntax for emitting a string in .NET 4.0+ is

```
<%: %>
```

Comment: Visual Studio wouldn't let me use <% %> in the tag. I guess I have to try it in the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Label is not contained within a databound control, you can't use databinding syntax (i.e. `<%#`). Either set the text of the Label in the code-behind, or do it inline like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%=String.Format("{0} {1}", Session("FirstName"), Session("LastName"))%>' ... />
```

Or in the code-behind:

```
Label1.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", Session("FirstName"), Session("LastName"))
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what the {0} {1} is for?

Comment: They're markers to specify where the parameters will be placed. For example, `String.Format("My first name is {0}, and my last name is {1}", "James", "Johnson")`. I prefer to use `String.Format` because it looks neater, but you could do this too: `Session("FirstName") & " " & Session("LastName")`

Comment: Oh ok, I tried using the first answer you wrote, but it showed up after the textbox before I entered a value. I changed the code to what you have as a 2nd answer but I can't figure out how to hide the text. It says lblIB.Visible is not declared but when I try to declare it As String it says Text is not a member of String

Comment: What? Can you update your code and include an example of how you're setting the visible property?

Comment: I took out the part where I declared it `As String` because @Icarus said I shouldn't need to do that. I still get the lblIB is not declared though.

Comment: So `IBTextBox` and `IBTextBoxButton` are still visible? Are you sure that the validation logic is working correctly? Have you set a breakpoint and walked through the logic to make sure `args.IsValid` is getting set correctly?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on. It says it's not loading a page but I don't know what that has to do with the labels.

Comment: It looks like it wouldn't work because I had it on the master page. I did that for styling purposes, but for functionality I threw the code on another page and so far it is fine.